# Looping a number count in Edge Animate

Tags: jquery-animate, adobe, adobe-edge

I am creating a banner in Adobe Edge Animate with a number count going from 0 to 1000, then slowly going to 1001... 1002... 1003... and then restarting/looping.
I have searched multiple online forums and I am using a code that I found in a previous post that works for the number count (see below), but I cannot get it to loop. Usually when I want to loop a banner I go to a specific time in the timeline and insert a trigger with

```
this.play (0);
```

This still loops the banner but not the loop count - it only displays the number 1000 until looping again. Any tips on how to go about this?

Here is link to my banner, when the flashing colors appear is when the banner is looping:

[Banner](http://clients.klirr.se/Kunder/test_pe/300x250_test/300x250_test.html)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
    var counter_delay = 0;
    var max_count = 1000;
    var present_count = 0;

    var timer = window.setInterval(stepUp,counter_delay);
    function stepUp(){
    present_count++;
    // Change the text of an element
    sym.$("Text").html(present_count);
    if(present_count==max_count)
    clearInterval(timer);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables are not working like this. You have to set and get Variables in Edge.

```
On Composition Ready
sym.setVariable("variablename", 0);


Get Value
var myVariable = sym.getVariable("variablename");

Change Value and Set it again
myVariable++; 
sym.setVariable("variablename", myVariable);
```

For your Loop i think you can use "onupdate" and just use: get variable, increase variable, set the Value for your Variable again.

Then, if your number is high enough, just set the variable to 0 again.